# Fody and Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location returns empty string

Tags: c#, reflection, fody, fody-costura

I was calling `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` in one of the dlls of a solution of mine. When I tried to use Fody (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody/) to package my binaries into a single binary, I noticed that this call started returning the empty string instead of the location of the executing assembly. Should this be considered a bug? And is there a way to get this information when using Fody? It seems to work fine if I make the call from the main project of my solution.

This is my main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"From Main: \"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location}\"");
    Console.WriteLine($"From dll:  \"{Class1.GetLocation()}\"");
}
```

And then the `GetLocation` method is defined in a dll like this:

```
public static string GetLocation()
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
}
```

The output in the console without Fody looks like this:

```
From Main: "C:\Prog\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe"
From dll:  "C:\Prog\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll"
```

While after adding Fody, it looks like this:

```
From Main: "C:\Prog\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe"
From dll:  ""
```

Comment: raise an issue here and ensure you follow all the steps in the template https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura), assemblies by default are loaded from memory, and therefore don't have a location.

To change this you can set [CreateTemporaryAssemblies](https://github.com/Fody/Costura#createtemporaryassemblies) in `FodyWeavers.xml` which will save the assemblies to a temporary location before loading them.

```
<Costura CreateTemporaryAssemblies='true' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`